# How can I check if the range of one dataframe is within the range of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes and I want to check if the Start, End ranges in DF1 are within the Start, End ranges in DF2 and for the ones that are true I want to print the ID and the region. I want to compare each row of DF1 to each row of DF2.

These are my dataframes:

```
DF1 = pd.DataFrame ({'Start':[500, 850, 1000],
                    'End':[700, 950, 1200],
                    'Region':["A", "B", "C"]})

DF2 = pd.DataFrame ({'Start':[200, 800, 1100],
                    'End':[750, 950, 1250],
                    'ID':[1, 2, 3]})
```

DF1

| Start | End | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 500 | 700 | A |
| 850 | 950 | B |
| 1000 | 1200 | C |
| 1100 | 1500 | D |

DF2

| Start | End | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 750 | 1 |
| 800 | 950 | 2 |
| 1100 | 1250 | 3 |

I assume that I have to write a for loop to iterate through all the rows. However, I am a beginner and I am having a hard time setting it up correctly.

This is the code I have tried so far.

```
for Start, End in DF1:
    if Start>=DF2["Start"] and End<=DF2["End"]:
      print (DF1["Region"], DF2["ID"])
```

However, I am getting this error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Any advice on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make this a fully running script so that answers can be tested. Initialize DF1 and etc.

Comment: Are you just chcking each row of DF1 to the same row in DF2, or is each Region being compared to every single ID in DF2?

Comment: I want to check each row of DF1 to all rows of DF2.

Comment: @pythonbeginner  Then my solution with cross join should fit your requirement.

Comment: @pythonbeginner  Any question on the solution ?   Feel free to let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can cross join the 2 dataframes by [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then use [`.query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to filter the rows with the required condition, as follows:

```
DF_out = DF1.merge(DF2, how='cross').query('(Start_x >= Start_y) & (End_x <= End_y)')
```

If your Pandas version is older than 1.2.0 (December 2020 version) and does not support `how='cross'`, you can use:

```
DF_out = DF1.assign(key=1).merge(DF2.assign(key=1), on='key').drop('key', axis=1).query('(Start_x >= Start_y) & (End_x <= End_y)')
```

**Result:**

`Start_x`, `End_x` are the original `Start`, `End` columns in `DF1`

`Start_y`, `End_y` are the original `Start`, `End` columns in `DF2`

```
print(DF_out)

   Start_x  End_x Region  Start_y  End_y  ID
0      500    700      A      200    750   1
4      850    950      B      800    950   2
```

You can then easily print the `Region` and `ID`, e.g.

```
print(DF_out['Region'])

0    A
4    B
Name: Region, dtype: object



print(DF_out['ID'])

0    1
4    2
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

If your checking criteria is strictly `<` or `>` rather than `<=` or `>=`, you can modify the comparison operator symbols in the `.query()`, as follows:

```
DF_out = DF1.merge(DF2, how='cross').query('(Start_x > Start_y) & (End_x < End_y)')
```

**Result:**

```
print(DF_out)

   Start_x  End_x Region  Start_y  End_y  ID
0      500    700      A      200    750   1
```

Comment: @pythonbeginner  As you need to check each row of DF1 to all rows of DF2, it is unavoidable you need to do some similar operation as cross join.   How about you break my codes into 2 steps.  That is, get the result of `.merge()` in a intermediate dataframe, then do the filtering with `.query()` in a separate step.  Take a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, breaking it up also causes google colab to crash. I am trying to figure out how to increase the Ram.

Comment: @pythonbeginner  Try splitting your dataframes into small pieces, run and combine the results.   E.g. `DF1` splitted into 4 pieces, each of around 20000x3.  Run the codes 4 times each with one of the 4 split pieces.  Something like that.

Comment: @pythonbeginner  Have you found a way to resolve your google colab crash issue yet ?   Recently, I found a way to greatly speed up the process and also reduce memory storage requirement.  See if you would like to try my new solution.  Let me know if you would like to.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), and is efficient for range joins as well, and is better than a naive cross join:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
# you can also install the dev version for the latest
# including the ability to use numba for faster performance
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
import pandas as pd

(DF1
.conditional_join(
    DF2, 
    ('Start', 'Start', '>='), 
    ('End', 'End', '<='))
)
   left             right
  Start  End Region Start  End ID
0   500  700      A   200  750  1
1   850  950      B   800  950  2
```

With the `dev` version, you can select the columns as well:

```py
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
import pandas as pd

(DF1
.conditional_join(
    DF2, 
    ('Start', 'Start', '>='), 
    ('End', 'End', '<='),
    df_columns='Region',
    right_columns='ID')
)

  Region  ID
0      A   1
1      B   2
```

With the `dev` version, if you have `numba` installed, you can enable it for more performance.